# PHPexcel upload not working with comment

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli, phpexcel

I am uploading .xlsx using PHPexcel and it was working fine, but when I used comment for some cells then its not working.

```
$exfile1  = $_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"];
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($exfile1);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "used comment for some cells"? Do you mean that you set Excel comments for some cells? If so, then you need to read them explicitly, because toArray() only returns cell data, not cell comments.... but PHPExcel does provide methods to check if there is a comment against a cell, and to retrieve that comment if it exists

Comment: e.g `$comments = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComments();` will return an associative array containing all comments against cells in that worksheet; or you can use `$comments = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('A1');` to retrieve any comments against a specific cell

Comment: It also helps if you explain what you mean by "not working".... does the script show any error messages? Does it display incorrect output? What do you expect to see? What do you actually see? Does it set your server on fire?

Comment: No there is no error message, only blank array. Actually i have just add a comment to cell and its not uploading and if i remove that comment then all working fine. i have googled also but didn't find any related topic to it.

Comment: How are you trying to see the comments? The `toArray()` method will not show comments? Are you using `getComments()`?

Comment: And what do you mean by "its not uploading" if you add comments.... PHPExcel doesn't do anything to upload a file, it just reads files